# react-apollo not firing query on first render

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

I'm building a React application using graphql and react-apollo.

I have worked with these libs before and, from my experience, when adding a query using `graphql` HOC to a component, the query should fire automatically on the first render. But for some reason this doesn't seem to work anymore.

I have this simple component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { getUser } from '../common/graphql/queries/user.query';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes = {} } = this.props;

    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <div className={classes.home}>
        Hello World!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default graphql(getUser, { name: 'getUser' })(Home);
```

I was expecting that the `getUser` query would fire automatically, but it is not being fired at all. If I check my network tab in Chrome there are no calls to graphql endpoint, even thought the `getUser` object is in my props.

[image]

But if I try to force a refetch, then the query works as expected:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fetch = true;
  }

  render() {
    const { classes = {} } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props);

    if(this.fetch) {
      this.props.getUser.refetch();
      this.fetch = false;
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.home}>
        Hello World!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

This is my apollo configuration:

```
import url from "url";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { withClientState } from "apollo-link-state";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";

import resolvers from "./common/graphql/resolvers";
import * as defaults from "./common/graphql/defaults";

const BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL || "http://localhost:8081";

console.log(BASE_URL);

const apollo = () => {

    // Server side rendering work around
    const httpLinkOptions = { uri: url.resolve(BASE_URL, "graphql") };
    const httpLink = new HttpLink(httpLinkOptions);

    const cache = new InMemoryCache({
        dataIdFromObject: ({ id }) => id
    });

    const stateLink = withClientState({
        cache,
        resolvers,
        defaults: { ...defaults, user: null, auth: null, categories: [] },
    });

    const link = ApolloLink.from([
        stateLink,
        httpLink
    ]);

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        link,
        cache,
        addTypename: false,
        dataIdFromObject: ({ id }) => id
    });

    return client;
};

export default apollo;
```

I have done some research and it seems it haven't occurred any major update recently that would change this behavior. Does anyone knows why this could be happening?

Comment: What version of `react-apollo` and `apollo-client` are you using? Can you post your client configuration?

Comment: react-apollo^2.1.3 and apollo-client^2.2.8. I'll edit with client config.

Comment: You've got a `dataIdFromObject` function that *should* work (as long as your ids are globally unique), but I suspect that, along with `addTypename` set to false are causing some unexpected behavior with regards to caching. I'm guessing `apollo-link-state` may be to blame.

Comment: Try commenting out the `dataIdFromObject` and `addTypename` options first and see if that helps. Otherwise, you might also try temporarily removing the State link.

Comment: `user` is coming back `null`, not `undefined`, so Apollo is acting like there was a cache hit, even though obviously the data is not in the cache

Comment: The problem was settings `user: null` in the `defaults` object. Once I removed it, it worked. But it doesnt make a lot of sense.. if the user is `null` in cache, shouldn't apollo try to fetch from network then?

Comment: If I changed the `fetchPolicy` to `cache-and-network` it works too.. I guess the problem was apollo thinks there is a cached user, even though the value is `null`. Still, doesn't make a lot of sense =S